# MessageHandlers not invoked when deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, rebus

I have an application which receive messages through a Azure ServiceBus using the Rebus library.

I observe a different behaviour when the application runs on Azure as a Web app, compared to when I run it locally.

When it runs in Azure, my message handlers are not being invoked.
Everything works as expected when the application runs local.

This is my setup.

In my web project Portal, Global.asax.cs:

```cs
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        _webContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        _queueContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        ConfigureWebContainer();
        _queueContainer.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<ServiceBusInstaller>());

        ApplicationInsightsConfig.Configure();
    }
```

In the project ServiceBus (where ServiceBusInstaller lies)

```cs
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    var adapter = new CastleWindsorContainerAdapter(container);
    var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("QueueUrl");

    var configurer = Configure
    .With(adapter)
    .Options(o =>
    {
        o.SimpleRetryStrategy(maxDeliveryAttempts: 0);
    })
    .Logging(l => l.Log4Net())
    .Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
        .MapAssemblyOf<ResetPasswordMessage>("Email"))
    Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(connectionString, "Email"));
    // Create and starts the bus
    configurer.Start();
}
```

My ResetPasswordHandler looks like this:

```
public class ResetPasswordHandler : IHandleMessages<ResetPasswordMessage>
{
    private readonly IContactAndEmailService _contactAndEmailService;

    public ResetPasswordHandler(IContactAndEmailService contactAndEmailService)
    {
        _contactAndEmailService = contactAndEmailService;
    }

    public async Task Handle(ResetPasswordMessage message)
    {
        _contactAndEmailService.SendEmail(message);
    }
}
```

I am using Service Bus Explorer to connect to the service bus, and I can see that the message is in the "email" queue. It does however stay there, and thus is not consumed.

Any pointers to either setup or azure subscribtion limitations or something else that can help me move forward is highly appreciated.

Comment: that sounds weird... could you try and lowercase the spelling of the queue name?

Comment: I just did that, and it actually worked. I had the wrong assumption, that it was case insensitive. Thanks a lot. You can post it as an answer and i'll accept it. Just for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might have something to do with the casing of the queue name, `Email`.

Could you try and make it lowercase throughout?